# CodeIgniter forms: Printing form_label and form_input on separate lines

Tags: codeigniter

I kindly need a programmer's support here.
 I am working on a web application using codeigniter (MVC framework) to generate some forms.

I would like to separate the form_label and the form_input such that the textbox is printed under the label in the user's view (AND NOT NEXT TO IT). I mean printing the label and input control on separate lines. can some one please advise? below is a code fragment:

```
$this->table->add_row(
        form_label('1.1 Izina ry\’Umuryango:', 'ovc_name'),form_input('ovc_name',isset($ovc['ovc_name'])?$ovc['ovc_name']:set_value('ovc_name')).' '.form_error('ovc_name'),
        form_label('1.2 Irindi zina (Izina rye ry\’idini):', 'ovc_middle_name'),form_input('ovc_middle_name',isset($ovc['ovc_middle_name'])?$ovc['ovc_middle_name']:set_value('ovc_middle_name')).' '.form_error('ovc_middle_name'),
        form_label('1.3 Andi mazina:', 'ovc_surname'),form_input('ovc_surname',isset($ovc['ovc_surname'])?$ovc['ovc_surname']:set_value('ovc_surname')).' '.form_error('ovc_surname'),
        form_label('1.4 Itariki y\’amavuko:', 'ovc_dob'),form_input('ovc_dob',isset($ovc['ovc_year_ob'])?$ovc['ovc_day_ob'].'-'.$ovc['ovc_month_ob'].'-'.$ovc['ovc_year_ob']:set_value('ovc_dob').' '.form_error('ovc_dob').'<img src="'.base_url().'/cside/images/cal.gif" onClick="displayCalendar(document.forms[0].ovc_dob,\'d-m-yyyy\',this)">'),
        form_label('1.5 Igitsina:', 'ovc_sex'),form_dropdown('ovc_sex',$ovc_sex,isset($ovc['ovc_sex'])?$ovc['ovc_sex']:'').' '.form_error('ovc_sex'),
        form_label('1.6 Nomero y\’irangamuntu:', 'ovc_nid'),form_input('ovc_nid',isset($ovc['ovc_nid'])?$ovc['ovc_nid']:set_value('ovc_nid')).' '.form_error('ovc_nid')
);
```

Comment: Do you mean underneath in the same cell or on a new row?

Comment: just in a new row. I can't figure out how to attach a form snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you the inputs to be underneath the label just put them on separate rows:

```
$this->table->add_row(
    form_label('1.1 Izina ry\’Umuryango:', 'ovc_name'),
    form_label('1.2 Irindi zina (Izina rye ry\’idini):', 'ovc_middle_name'),
    form_label('1.3 Andi mazina:', 'ovc_surname'),
    form_label('1.4 Itariki y\’amavuko:', 'ovc_dob'),
    form_label('1.5 Igitsina:', 'ovc_sex'),
    form_label('1.6 Nomero y\’irangamuntu:', 'ovc_nid')
);

$this->table->add_row(
    form_input('ovc_name', isset($ovc['ovc_name']) ? $ovc['ovc_name'] : set_value('ovc_name')) . ' ' . form_error('ovc_name'),
    form_input('ovc_middle_name', isset($ovc['ovc_middle_name']) ? $ovc['ovc_middle_name'] : set_value('ovc_middle_name')) . ' ' . form_error('ovc_middle_name'),
    form_input('ovc_surname', isset($ovc['ovc_surname']) ? $ovc['ovc_surname'] : set_value('ovc_surname')) . ' ' . form_error('ovc_surname'),
    form_input('ovc_dob', isset($ovc['ovc_year_ob']) ? $ovc['ovc_day_ob'] . '-' . $ovc['ovc_month_ob'] . '-' . $ovc['ovc_year_ob'] : set_value('ovc_dob') . ' ' . form_error('ovc_dob') . '<img src="' . base_url() . '/cside/images/cal.gif" onClick="displayCalendar(document.forms[0].ovc_dob,\'d-m-yyyy\',this)">'),
    form_dropdown('ovc_sex', $ovc_sex, isset($ovc['ovc_sex']) ? $ovc['ovc_sex'] : '') . ' ' . form_error('ovc_sex'),
    form_input('ovc_nid', isset($ovc['ovc_nid']) ? $ovc['ovc_nid'] : set_value('ovc_nid')) . ' ' . form_error('ovc_nid')
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Absolom, is this what you were after?

Answer (score 0):

[From CI user guide.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html) 
You can set style with:

```
$tmpl = array (
                    'table_open'          => '<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">',

                    'heading_row_start'   => '<tr>',
                    'heading_row_end'     => '</tr>',
                    'heading_cell_start'  => '<th>',
                    'heading_cell_end'    => '</th>',

                    'row_start'           => '<tr>',
                    'row_end'             => '</tr>',
                    'cell_start'          => '<td>',
                    'cell_end'            => '</td>',

                    'row_alt_start'       => '<tr>',
                    'row_alt_end'         => '</tr>',
                    'cell_alt_start'      => '<td>',
                    'cell_alt_end'        => '</td>',

                    'table_close'         => '</table>'
              );

$this->table->set_template($tmpl);
```

Comment: This is really answering the OP's question.